# Why does Idris think a prefix of an identifier is a keyword?

Tags: idris, internals

When trying to interpret this code

```
injective : {A : Type} ->
            {P : A -> Type} ->
            ((x : A) -> P x) ->
            Type
```

I get the error

```
   |
14 | injective : {A : Type} ->
   |           ^
not a terminator
```

which really confused my. When I write `private` over the declaration, the error seems to go away, so I guess those access modifiers really change the way parsing works. However, I don't understand why that should be.

So why does that error show up? Why does the parser think `in` is a keyword (which I'm guessing is the problem) instead of part of an identifier, if I don't place `private` just before?

[EDIT]: To get the error, this code should be enough:

```
Subset : Type -> Type
Subset a = a -> Type

syntax [x] "in" [y] = y x

Test : Type
Test = Nat

injective : {a, b : Type} ->
            (a -> b) ->
            Type
injective {a} {b} f = (x, y : a) ->
                      f x = f y ->
                            x = y
```

I'm using Idris 1.3.1's interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

Your code compiles just fine for me. When I had the `not a terminator` errors in the past it was almost always due to some indentation mistake I made. But I have no idea what the `private` modifier would change, so that it works in your case.

Comment: Ok, sorry, I shoud've tested it before posting. I've narrowed down the code need for the error to the one in the question.

Comment: Ok, at least now I can confirm that it does not compile. Either changing the syntax to something like `foo` will work, or using a modifier as you said.